# How to prove $ \int _0 ^1 \left ( \sqrt{1-x^2}\right )^n dx = \prod_{k=1} ^n \frac {2k}{2k+1} $

Tags: integration

How to prove this integral identity?

$$ \int _0 ^1 \left (  \sqrt{1-x^2}\right )^n dx = \prod_{k=1} ^n \frac {2k}{2k+1} $$

---

↑ This identity is false. It should be corrected to $ \int _0 ^1 \left ( {1-x^2}\right )^n dx = \prod_{k=1} ^n \frac {2k}{2k+1} $

I'm sorry for causing confusion

Comment: For $n=1$ the integral is $\pi/4$.

Comment: Is $n$ even or odd?

Comment: Another approach, you can use beta function either setting $x=\sin t$ or $u=x^2$. See [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/853111/123277).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$I_{n+1}:=\int _0 ^1 \left (  \sqrt{1-x^2}\right )^n dx =\int _{-\frac{\pi}{2}} ^0 \left (  \sqrt{1-\sin^2 t}\right )^n \cos t dt=\int _{-\frac{\pi}{2}} ^0 \cos^{n+1} t dt=$$
integrating by parts
$$\left[\sin t \cos^{n}t\right]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} ^0+n\int _{-\frac{\pi}{2}} ^0 \sin t\cos^{n-1} t \sin t dt=n\int _{-\frac{\pi}{2}} ^0 \cos^{n-1} t (1-\cos^2 t) dt$$
$$=n\int _{-\frac{\pi}{2}} ^0 \cos^{n-1} t dt-n\int _{-\frac{\pi}{2}} ^0 \cos^{n+1} t  dt=nI_{n-1}-nI_{n+1}$$
Hence: $$I_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}I_{n-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Start with a change of variable $x=\sin(y)$. So $$I_n=\int _0 ^1 \left ( \sqrt{1-x^2}\right )^n~ dx = \int _0 ^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{n+1}(y) ~dy$$ and now use integration by reduction method as described in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: there is an error. this is $\cos^{n+1}$ on the first line, see Dario's answer.

Comment: You are right ! Sorry for the typo. Thanks :(

Answer (score 1):

Use the change of variables $x = \sin t$. You get the Wallis integral.

If you don't know haw to handle it, start with an integration by parts.